# Spring Data Redis not importing correctly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I'm currently working on a project that requires me to use Spring Data Redis. However, I can't seem to get it working, because if I do an import of org.springframework.data, it doesn't recognize the .data. I included my pom.xml file below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <systemPath>${basedir}\src\lib\spring-data-redis-2.7.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: please try `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` instead if data-redis

Answer (score 0):

I would be looking at your `<systemPath>`, I have no issues using the exact code without the system path. the systemPath is primarily for if you have a local copy of that lib in a specific spot. if that is the case make sure the local copy you have on your machine matches the version and groupId etc. if you don't have the files already installed in a directory locally just get rid of that line all together.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I was simply missing clicking the recompile button for the pom.xml, it works now